# Apache/Ruby/Passenger misconfigured after Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 update

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger, redmine

Well, I have to admit, that I'm down today. I've updated my Ubuntu and that rendered Redmine 2.1.2 completely dead. Any suggestions as of to what should I update or reconfigure? I'm trying not to use Ruby/Rails/Passenger blindly but it's tough as it's not my expertise. I'd like to USE Redmine instead.

Top of the Passenger error log is below, but feel free to check whole page at http://redmine.teacloud.net:

```
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

bundle install
If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

Is this app supposed to be run as the nobody user?
Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
-------- The exception is as follows: -------

Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
```

• I have no idea, what user should this app supposed to be run as. Everything else uses www-data by default, however the redmine application folder in filesystem is owner by root.

• Everything was working for two years on ruby 1.8 that is not on my system now. I've managed to install lowest version 1.8.7, latest 2.1.2... and I have no idea where does the 1.9.1 get from.

• I don't understand how 'bundle install' and 'bundle update' is related to current ruby version switched to using rvm.

• I am not sure, at what point will my Redmine MySQL database be migrated or destroyed if I'll need to upgrade Redmine (so I have backup).

• bundle install didn't help, Apache runs ruby 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simply as follows (whole failure path is documented here http://www.redmine.org`enter code here`/boards/2/topics/43500?r=43514):

• Everything happens in the Redmine's installation folder:

• Went to GitHub (https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/Gemfile) and copied fresh database section to Redmine's Gemfile (ignoring the fact that I have Redmine 2.1.2 and Gemfile is far newer)

```
$ rvm use system
$ bundle install
```